# how does this transaction size calculated

Tags: transaction-fees

what brought my attention [this transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/fc1731fbf666284585a253f390e8868e0307b667cd5bc37cf2ef0f1a578c1e30) size

this transaction contains 2 SegWit inputs which mean it should be compressed and five outputs.

As we know, each compressed input size is ≈ 148 bytes, and each output is 34.

So transactions size should be (148 * 2) + (5 * 34) + 10 = 476

But actual transaction size is 516 Byte.

---

is it a multi-signature transaction? if so is all other transaction which has one signature has a size of 148 Byte?

> I apologize for not being word-perfect in English

Comment: Why did you delete the question?

Comment: Because I have to read more about input scripts. I've seen that some input scripts are longer than the usual ones. So I guess I miss something.

Comment: I've restored it in case you got something good to share.